# setting readable and writable in java doesn't work

Tags: java

I had made an exe wrapper for my java application which asks for administrative password and changes the permissions of an administrative file with the setReadable(true) method. The method returns true i.e. the operation succeeds but nothing happen the files still retain administrative permissions

Comment: Is there a reason why it shouldn't?

Comment: It is what I don't know I had made more  than 20 Google searches but nothing helps

Comment: I had created a folder in Program Files directory , called Page Book and then created the files in the Page Book folder

Comment: Does the program work if you run it directly from the command line from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Do you mean cmd prompt with administrative privillage by elevated command prompt

Comment: The program is a console application that runs on a command user interface and asks the user for administrator password on startup

Comment: You mean the UAC popup like [this](https://cdn.howto-connect.com/wp-content/uploads/uac_dialog_box_new.png)?

Comment: No it is an application i built called  Page Book Installer.exe

Comment: So you ask the user to type in the system password in plain text? That is not a very secure way of gaining administrator privileges. You may want to consider asking the user to authenticate the startup of the app using a UAC popup instead.

Also, if you do not see a UAC popup, it is possible that your program is not running with administrator privileges. Try right clicking the exe file and selecting "Run as Administrator".

Comment: My user provides the administrative password in the UAC popup and not in my program

Comment: I ask again. Why should setting read or write permissions affect other permissions?

Comment: the setRead and write comments tells that they have succeeded in removing administrative privillages from files in 'Page Book' folder (they return 'true') but the files still hold administrative permissions and my another program which does not administrative privillages cannot manipulate them

Comment: `/*a code segment that runs with administrative privillage*/
        File f=new File("C:/Program Files/Page Book/Data.txt");
        System.out.println(f.canWrite());
        try{
        FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("C:/Program Files/Page Book/Data.txt");
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(fs);
        ps.println("C:/users/gullu's/desktop");
        ps.close();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}`

Comment: Output:
true
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Page Book\Data.txt (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)

Comment: OK, I ran the following code:

`FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("C:/Program Files/Test/Log.txt", true);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fs);
ps.println("Test");
ps.close();`

With administrator privileges on Windows 10 and Java 8, and it ran without any errors. Which Operating System and Java version are you using?

Comment: sorry I had made a mistake ,the code is not the one which runs as administrator.